# How do I pass in a parameter called 'controller' in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actioncontroller

I have a controller that expects a parameter called `controller` and the RSpec test I wrote doesn't seem to like the fact that I'm passing in it as a parameter with `get`.

### The spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PageHelpsController do

  describe 'GET :search' do

    it "returns" do
      get :search, { :controller => 'employer', :action => 'edit', :edition => 'usa', :anchor => 'collaborator' }
      response.status.should be_success
      response.should render_template(:partial => 'shared/page_help')
    end
  end

end
```

### The error

```
vagrant@debian-squeeze64:/vagrant$ bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/page_helps_controller_spec.rb 
F

Failures:

  1) PageHelpsController GET :search returns
     Failure/Error: Unable to find /vagrant/spec/controllers/page_helps_controller_spec.rb to read failed line
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"employer", :action=>"search", :relative_url_root=>nil, :edition=>"usa"}
     # ./spec/controllers/page_helps_controller_spec.rb:11
```

Comment: To clarify, is there a controller named Employer or did you create a parameter called controller?

Comment: Parameter called controller, as mentioned in title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a shot at this question assuming you created a parameter named `controller`.

The problem is you are confusing Rails by creating a parameter called `controller`. It's assuming there is a controller called `Employer` which of course doesn't exist. That is why you are receiving the route error. To solve this, you will have to change the parameter named `controller` to something else.